# Array as QueryParam is not being processed in POST

Tags: java, rest, jersey, extjs4.2

I have the following Java REST method I implemented using Jersey:

```
@POST
@Path("copy")
public List<Integer> copyCompanionTextRule(@QueryParam("ruleid") List<Integer> ruleIdList, 
                                           @QueryParam("workgroupid") List<WorkgroupId> workgroupIds,
                                           @Context HttpHeaders hh)
throws ETMSException 
{
    List<Integer> insertedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if ( null != ruleIdList ){
        for(Integer ruleId : ruleIdList) {
            insertedItems.addAll(copyCompanionTextRule(ruleId, workgroupIds));
        }
    }
    return insertedItems;
}
```

It receives a list of integer and a list of objects of type WorkgroupId as well as the context for some extra processing I'll do later.

I'm working the client with Sencha EXTJS 4.2 and my request is being performed this way:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/sysadmin/companiontextrules/copy',
            method: 'POST',
            showException: true,
            scope: this,
            params: {
                ruleid: Ext.encode(ruleIdsArray),
                workgroupid: toWorkgroups
            },
            callback: function(options, success, response) {
                me.setLoading(false);

                if (!success) {
                    return;
                }
                this.destroy();    
            }
        });
```

The ruleIdsArray is just an array of integers: [1274,1292,1745].
The toWorkgroups is an array of objects which has a model that is related to the WorkgroupId entity.

As you can see, both lists are being processed as query parameters and I'm using the "params" config in the Ajax request; however, this is not working.

Seems like the ruleId array is empty, when it tries to iterate the rulesIdList is empty so the method POST works but it is returning always an empty list.

I know I cannot use them in the form "url?ruleid=a&workgroupid=b". When I tried it just by curiosity, I got a QueryParamException and NumberFormatException saying that the rule array is being considered as string.

When I use the "Ext.encode" for both params I receive a message in browser console that the Maximum callstack size exceeded.

This is what I got from Chrome Console:

[image]

I've tried almost everything, but maybe some more eyes can help me in this, I'd really appreciate comments or any kind of help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your parameters are going in the POST body instead of as query parameters.

url?ruleid=a&workgroupid=b is getting a NumberFormatException because ruleId is supposed to be Integer.

url?ruleid=1&workgroupid=b or url?ruleid=1&ruleid=2&workgroupid=b should work

Comment: I thought that ExtJS has some mechanism o handle query params through the "params" config. I took a look to some code in the application and realize that the "params" config is used by some devs when the method is GET. For the POST, I did it as you suggested and worked fine. The array can be big, so I'd probably need to request another way to handle that, I do not want very extensive URLs. Thanks!